# How do I use a for loop to plot multiple graphs with layout()?

Tags: r, for-loop, layout, plot

I want to make 4 plots using layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2)). I know how to make them separately by writing the plot() code four times. How can I use a for loop instead?
My code now is:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 2))
plot(density(y1))
plot(density(y2))
plot(density(y3))
plot(density(y4))
```

Answer (score 1):

To make everyone happy: put your data in an object like a matrix or data.frame and then just loop over every column:

```
df <- data.frame(y1, y2, y3, y4)
for(col in 1:ncol(df)) {
    plot(density(df[, col]))
}
```